# Must Backbone el be an element in the Dom and not in the template?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm learning Backbone and am wondering if in Backbone, when defining `el` in our views, must `el` be an element in the `DOM` and not an element defined inside our template?

Comment: Good practice rely of elements view has in its template, you can define el with outer elem but its not secure, as you cant be sure this el exists

Comment: So you're saying that good practice dictates that `el` should be an element within our template as opposed to defining `el` as an already existent element in the DOM?

Comment: Yep, view can use only elements from its own template. The only exсeption - bootstrap view u start app with. It needs existing dom as el to start

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that it really matters in essence and unless I'm missing something obvious, I don't understand how defining the el in the template would be safer.
I tend to define my `el` as an existing DOM element that serves as a wrapper for the view template, but at times I also define it at runtime, depending on the situation.

The concept of `el`en `views` in general are related to `Event bubbling`, which is functionality that is provided by the public DOM api.
Generally it means that events captured by inner elements, will be propagated to outer elements.

In terms of Backbone View objects, it means that when you define an `el`, it serves as the parent element for the DOM section that is represented by the View. When you define events on its descendants in the View object, el will register the events that are captured and propagated by its child elements, unless you decide to prevent the event from bubbling, which can be achieved by `event.stopPropagation()`.

In my conclusion, I think that you are flexible in how you use this theory and that the choice depends on the situation you are currently dealing with.
Anyhow, the question may be a bit malformed, since el must always be an element in the DOM before it can deal with events.

Comment: imagine, on one of your views you rely on outer el, for example make popup, so u define el with .outer-selector. But .outer-selector was rendered by other view and by some reasons was closed and removed its DOM. As a result first view cant do its job, u will have spagetti with cross-selectors with no idea what is going on between views and very soon u will get untestable code

Comment: You can as easily solve by first rendering an HTML layout, followed by creating a view on an existing piece of HTML in the DOM. You will not have spaghetti if you know how to structure your code and use objects to glue your views. No offense intended, but for me this sounds like a strange set of arguments to claim that your el should be within your view template.